# How to maintain session in javascript while using webview in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Local storage is not working?

When using cookies alert always shown empty alert.

please help?

Answer (score 0):

**See the examples of local storage:**

Setting values: `localStorage.myname = "Test";`

Getting values: `localStorage.myname;` // returns "Greg"

More information here for local storage: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

For Windows Phone 7 : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

*The syntax is as below ;*

```
localStorage.setItem("name", "Phonegap");

localStorage.getItem("name");  //will return Phonegap
```

Comment: local storage not working in webview, any other way to maintain the session

Comment: When i set this below code in webview...

localStorage.username = employeecode;

error message shown as...

11-19 00:05:10.242: I/chromium(1707): [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'username' of null", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/common.js (12)